# How to match only the rows where the first two letters of the content in the rows are not equal

Tags: r

```
NET_tech2 <- NET_tech %>% 
 pairwise_count(item=Nuts2,feature = Appln_id) %>%
 arrange(desc(n))
```

which gives,

```
# A tibble: 640 x 3
   item1 item2     n
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 CH01  CH02     14
 2 CH02  CH01     14
 3 DE94  DEA3      7
 4 CH02  CH03      7
 5 CH03  CH02      7
 6 DEB3  DE71      7
 7 DEA3  DE94      7
 8 DE71  DEB3      7
 9 ITC1  ITH5      6
10 ITH5  ITC1      6
# … with 630 more rows
```

I have done this so far, item 1 and item 2 represents nuts2 regions, n represents number of links between these regions. The first two letter of the nuts2 items represents country codes. Now i want to get only the links that are across borders (transnational links), that means i have to get rid of the rows where the first two letters in item 1 is equal to the first two letters in item 2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `filter` on the substring of both columns to do a comparison

```
library(dplyr)
NET_tech2   %>%
   filter(substr(item1, 1, 2) != substr(item2, 1, 2))
```